# _colorIndex and _symbolIndex when creating object

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Good day,

Im currently on a project that uses javascript as it's front end im having a hard time figuring out why does everytime that im creating a object there will be always a _symbolIndex and _colorIndex in the object.

ex. my codes looks like this.

```
    test_data = {
        name: data[i].number,
        data: reply_stats*100
    };

    series_value.push(test_data);
```

the test_data object has

Object

```
_colorIndex:0
_symbolIndex:0
data:25
name:"09356152280"
```

but i only add name and data.

i used this for the highcharts

thanks in advance

Comment: The question is what is series_value? If this is an object provided by external plugin for your graph library, possibly it is not just an array.push function but some decorated one that is first adding the additional properties and then pushing to some internal array. You should start your investigation from checking the definition of series_value.push() method.

Comment: Paste your full code and try to be more specific on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, haven't found it in the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) (maybe it is there, I just haven't picked it up). So I went investigating a bit.

Turns out Highcharts autoinserts metadata `_colorIndex` and `_symbolIndex` properties into a serie object that is passed alone or as an array element into their `series` property. 
If the object being passed already has `_indexColor` and `_symbolIndex`, for example from the previous loading into the chart, then these `_someprefixIndex`properties will not be modified. 
Otherwise, if these properties do not exist, new propertis will be autoinserted into each serie object (in the array passed to `series` property) in the following way:

- autoinsert will start a counter value from 0 and incrementing it on each insert.

Not knowing this can lead to a problem that I had. The `_colorIndex` will dictate the autocoloring of series on the chart. I ended up having the same color for two series that I expected to be autocolored in different color. It was due to the fact I added one serie, for example i referred to it in my code as

```
var serieA = {
  name: "Temperature",
  data: [34, 32, ...]
}
```

Then I added another serie similarly, `serieB` as

```
var series = [
  serieA,
  serieB
]
```

It turned out that `serieA` already had `_colorIndex === 0` from first loading, and `serieB` got the same `_colorIndex === 0` on autoinsert

Hope it helps someone